# Wordpress website home page loading issue

Tags: wordpress, web, e-commerce

I have website fotohediyye.az it is a wordpress e commerce website. So everything was ok until I began seo things and installed yoast seo then google analytics then I ran speed test and it was awful. After it won't load. My worpdress website not loading. Why is it happening what to do?

Comment: did you try uninstalling those plugins if the problem still here. I think you question may be close because not enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

Reset Your Permalink Settings and to POST NAME &
Check And Fix Problems With Your .htaccess File

Comment: Can you explain in details?

Comment: Check 1 : you can change your .htaccess file which is located in root path of your wordpress project... 

You can get code from Here - Link : ```https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/```

Check 2 : in your Admin Panel you have to change Permalink Settings,

Admin > Settings > Permalinks > Post Name > Save